# Deploy WSO2 API Manager on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2

I'm trying to deploy the WSO2 API manager solution (v 1.4.0) on a m1.medium Amazon EC2 instance.

I followed these steps : http://dist.wso2.org/products/api-manager/1.4.0/APIManager-GettingStarted-v1.4.0.pdf and everything seemed to work fine.

I have the access to the following URL : XXXXX:9443/carbon/

but I couldn't access the following URLs :

- List item  XXXXXX:9763/publisher
- List item XXXXXX:9763/store

These URLs return timeout error.

The following information appear after running "sh wso2server.sh"

> [2013-09-02 13:58:08,838]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 64 sec
>
> [2013-09-02 13:58:09,229]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : XXXXX:9443/carbon/
>
> [2013-09-02 13:58:09,230]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : XXXXX:9763/publisher
>
> [2013-09-02 13:58:09,230]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : XXXXXX:9763/store

I'v searched for more information without any success. Did I miss something deploying the WSO2 API Manager on an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: Are  all the ports open at EC2 instance?

Comment: Even if the indicated port was 9763, the port to use was in reality 9443... It works now.

Comment: Yes all the ports were open

Comment: This should work..Check the transport protocols..ie: http/https.

Comment: Management console is accessed via  https://host:9443, store and publisher is accessed via http://host:9763